# What is "Symbol"?

Tags: binding, linker, frameworks, symbols

I am studying about Framework and Library
If you look at the Framework Programming Guide of the Apple Documentation Archive, the word "Symbol" appears frequently, but I don't understand the meaning of the word "Symbol" here
For example, I don't know the exact meaning of "Symbol" in the sentence "For static linked shared libraries, the symbols in the library are checked at link time to make sure they exist."

I've looked up a lot about "Symbol" on Google, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for
Can I ask for an easy explanation?

Answer (score 0):

**Symbol** in programming languages is the human-readable **name** given by programmer to some numeric value.

There are two kinds of symbols:
Plain **numeric symbol** represents a constant value specified when the program was written and it does not change, for instance `Dozen EQU 12`.

**Address symbol** represents position in the program, as if you have pointed at some line of the program with your finger and said: this address will be named `_start:`.
The exact value of address symbols is not known when the program is written, it depends on how the linker arranged program section in the final file and where will be the program image loaded to memory at run time.

Program may be linked from several separately compiled modules or libraries, and each module can refer external symbols publicly defined in some of the other modules. Linker reads symbol tables from linked modules  and for each symbol declared as **external** it looks for a homonymous symbol defined in other modules as **global** or **public**. Thats how I comprehend the quoted sentence in your question. See also [Symbol in assembly language](https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/index.htm#Symbols).